# How to get the list of all users in a discord server in the version 1.5.x

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to get the list of all users in a discord server, i used the classic method

`await ctx.send(guild.members)` but this returned only the bot itself.

The output was

`[<Member id=******************* name='test' discriminator='1740' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=**************** name='My server' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=6>>]`

The total of members is in fact 6 as mentioned `member_count` but how to get a list of all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the new version of discord.py(1.5.x), there're some updates about `Intents`. Intents are similar to permissions, you have to define Intents to get channels, members and some events etc. You have to define it before defining the `client = discord.Bot(prefix='')`.

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Bot(prefix='', intents=intents)

@client.command()
async def all_members(ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.guild.members)
```

If you want to get more information about Intents, you can look at the [API References](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents).

Comment: Firstly i think you meant `discord.Intents()` because there is no method called `Intent`, and i am still studying the docs now, but I am getting this error, ```discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.``` which among the two options would you suggest

Comment: Go to [this](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) address then go to the `Bot`. After that enable the `Privileged Gateway Intents`.